# Why do NPCs become hostile outside of restricted areas?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I"m playing Assassin's Creed IV: Black Flag for the first time, and have recently reached Havana. I know that if I enter the "restricted areas" (red areas on the minimap), I will be attacked if spotted. However soldiers are randomly becoming hostile to me when I'm just exploring, even when I'm nowhere near either restricted areas or any other interesting things (loot chests, manuscripts, etc.)

How does NPC hostility work in this game outside of explicitly restricted areas? Are all rooftops "soft" restricted? Is there some way of knowing whether walking/climbing/jumping into a specific place outside of a restricted area will cause nearby soldiers to become hostile?